# FindByAny in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Is there any option in hibernate like matching query string with any of the fields in the table and show the result?

I have customers table, if i type a string and search, it should search all the fields in the customers table and show the matching rows.

I created a named query findByAny like this but that didnt work

```
@NamedQuery(name = "CustomerMaster.findByAny", query = "SELECT c FROM CustomerMaster c WHERE c.customerName like :query or c.phone1 = :query")
```

Comment: Can't you pass two parameters and when calling the query create the like parameter from the string that is entered, e.g. `String likequery = "%" + query + "%";`? The query would then be `...WHERE c.customerName like :likequery or c.phone1 = :query` and you'd set both parameters on the query object.

Comment: This will work. Just want to find out is there anyway i can do by passing a single string. i have to check against 8 fields in that table.